# Can't access api.quickblox.com/session.xml

Tags: quickblox

When I try to access api.quickblox.com/session.xml to create a session, I get a 404 error.

I tried to access it in both browser and c#.
In the browser I get:

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

In C# I get

> System.WebException: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use POST request (not GET) to access to this API

Please read here http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Requests_and_Responses